# Flip all groups of consecutive 0 bits of size <= N to 1s

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Say I have an unsigned M-bit integer (where M is one of 8, 16, 32, 64), with various runs of 0-bits inside it:

...111 000 11 00 1 0000 1 0 1 00000 111...

Given a number N where 0 <= N <= M, I'd like to fill all the groups of 0s in the integer that are <=N in size. So if for the above integer we were given N=3, the result would be:

...111 **111** 11 **11** 1 0000 1 **1** 1 00000 111...

Notice that the 4 group and 5 group of zeroes are not flipped, because their size is > 3.

How would I approach writing an efficient implementation in C/C++? I assume there is some clever bit twiddling I could do, but I'm not sure where to start. I've seen multiplication used to propogate a bit pattern but not with this sort of variable length checking. Lookup tables seem painful for the same reason. A well placed subtraction of 1 can flip a run of bits, but figuring out what to subtract looks tricky.

Edit: To be clear, although M is fixed at compile time, N can vary at runtime.

Comment: For N=8, the obvious solution is a lookup table. It's small and I don't think you'll be able to outperform it.

Comment: @R.. sure, but for N=24 and M=64, the problem is a little trickier.  I don't think a specialized approach will beat the the nieve aproach by much for the general case.

Comment: @R..: N varies at runtime, so you would need 8 lookup tables.

Comment: 6, I think. If N=0, it's a no-op, and if N=M, it's just replacing any input with -1.

Comment: Couldn't it be dealt with 1 byte at a time?

Comment: No, because the zero-runs spanning two or more bytes have lengths longer than their length in a single byte window.

Comment: I can think of some simple O(N) ways to "shrink" the runs such that the short (<=N) runs disappear entirely and the longer runs remain, shortened. This might lead to a decent solution.

Comment: @R..: Interesting, example?

Comment: See my answer. No idea if it's right.

Comment: Just tested and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Out of curisosity - why do you need this? :-)

Comment: Awesome question and @R..'s answer (if it works fine, I didn't tested). I'm curious about the use of that too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = ~x;
for (j = 1; j <= N/2; j *= 2) x &= (x >> j);
x &= (x >> (N - j + 1));
for (j = 1; j <= N/2; j *= 2) x |= (x << j);
x |= (x << (N - j + 1));
x = ~x;
```

Same idea as the solution by R.., but a little bit optimized.

---

To optimize more, it is possible to eliminate second loop:

```
t = ~x;
m = x & (t << 1);
for (j = 1; j <= N/2; j *= 2) t &= (t >> j);
t &= (t >> (N - j + 1));
t |= ((m - t) & ~m);
x = ~t;
```

Here the only remaining loop shifts away bit groups (exactly as in previous variant), but instead of second loop, a simple bitwise trick is used to restore longer-than-N groups.

---

Example (N = 4):

```
input string  110000100000011
inverted one  001111011111100
loop iter. 1  000111001111100
loop iter. 2  000001000011100
one more iter 000000000001100
```

First loop iteration works properly because each bit group is preceded by at least one zero bit. As a result we have at least two zero bits preceding each bit group. So it is possible to shift by two bits at once on second loop iteration. For the same reason third loop iteration may shift by 4 bits at once, etc. But this example doesn't need shift larger than two bits. Since loop has shifted bit groups by 3 bits already, we have to shift them by N-3=1 bit more (which is done by next line after the loop).

Now smaller bit group disappeared, but larger one is represented by a pair of bits. To reconstruct the remaining group(s), second loop may be used:

```
starting with 000000000001100
loop iter. 1  000000000011100
loop iter. 2  000000001111100
one more iter 000000011111100
result        111111100000011
```

Or instead of the second loop, we may use a bitwise trick:

```
m             010000100000000
t             000000000001100
m-t           010000011110100
(m-t) & ~m    000000011110100
t|((m-t)&~m)  000000011111100
result        111111100000011
```

`m` marks the beginning of each group. `m-t` restores all shifted-out bits. The next operation clears unused bits of `m`. One more operation is needed to combine restored bits with the bits remaining after the shifting loop.

---

Benchmark results (AMD K8, GCC 4.6.3 -O2), seconds:

```
N one_loop two_loops unoptimized
1     3.9     4.2       3.3
2     4.6     6.2       5.2
3     4.6     6.2       7.1
4     5.6     7.9       8.9
5     5.6     7.9      11.3
6     5.6     7.9      13.3
15    6.7    10.0      46.6
```

Comment: Interesting. I suspect which version is actually faster depends a lot on the particular CPU model. Yours has roughly half as many steps, but variable-length shifts which are pathologically slow on some really bad CPU models. It would be interesting to see some benchmarks.

Comment: Also, I suspect unrolling might even switch which version wins.

Comment: @R..: not half as many steps, but O(log N) steps, instead of O(N). Added benchmark results, but probably they are not very interesting because K8 is pretty old CPU (by the way, it computes variable-length shifts very efficiently).

Comment: Oh, I didn't even look at the loop step. Yes, your version is more efficient then. I suspect if you propagate N as a constant and unroll the loops, it will win even for small N.

Comment: Marked as correct, but I'm going to have to spend some time digesting this magic :) I can more intuitvely see how R's answer is finding runs of bits then filling them back in, but what really is going on here? You're increasing the amount you shift by each time (why is this safe?) and then it looks like you're running a tweaked last iteration of each for loop by hand (why?)...

Comment: @JosephGarvin: I've added an example and some more explanations. Hope this helps to understand everything better.

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this:

```
x = ~x;
for (i=0; i<N; i++) x&=x/2;
for (i=0; i<N; i++) x|=x*2;
x = ~x;
```

The not operation is to account for the fact that zeros "shift in" at the top rather than ones. You could avoid it by bringing in a one in the top bit manually; then the `&=` and `|=` steps would reverse too.

By the way, if this does work, you'll probably want to write an unrolled version for each N rather than using those loops.

Comment: It seems to messup at the lower end.

Comment: I removed the code without the nots again because I couldn't get it to work right off.. probably something stupid. Are you having problems with the original version too?

Comment: Yeah, it messes up atleast when the LSBs are 0s of more than N in number. Case: `10000`.

Comment: Works fine in that case here... Are you perhaps using signed types?

Comment: My mistake. Works well with unsigned types.

Comment: Cool :) Upvoted, works and kicked off people thinking about it, but I marked Evgeny as accepted because of his improved big-O bound.

Comment: Thanks. Any answers on what it's used for?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: For this problem, `R..`'s solution is better unless `N` is relatively large (on my machine, the crossover point for `M = 32` is around `N = 18`, but that's testing with all possible 32-bit numbers, which might not represent the intended use). So I upvoted that solution, but I'm leaving mine here because it shows how to iterate over spans of `0`s (or, with a small modification `1`s) in a word, and that might be useful for other purposes.

---

Here's your example, with the ranges and preceding 1's marked:

```
111 000 11 00 1 0000 1 0 1 00000 111
  1 000  1 00        1 0
```

Suppose we subtract '1' from each of those ranges: (relative to the range, not a real 1)

```
  0 111  0 11        0 1
```

And add that back to the original:

```
111 111 11 11 1 0000 1 1 1 00000 111
```

OK, that's looking good. So we need to figure out all of the `1`s to subtract, which would be the position of the last `0` in every range of size less ≤ N. And to figure out the size of the range, we need to find the preceding `1` as well.

So, basically we need to find all of the spans of `0`s by alternating searches for the last `0` and the last `1`, taking care to set the trailing bits to all `1`s or all `0`s. If the range is not too large, then we can subtract the bit in the position of the last `0` and add back the `1` in the position of the last 1, which will turn all the `0`s in the span into `1`s. I fear that was not very clear, so let's try some code.

The first thing are the following little functions:

```
unsigned int last_one(unsigned int k) { return k & -k; }
unsigned int last_zero(unsigned int k) { return (k + 1) & ~k; }
```

Try that until you're convinced it works. Note that both of them return a single one bit, or a zero if there isn't any `last_{one,zero}`

Next, how big is the span? It would be a bit of a pain to count the `0`s because that involves finding positions (not that difficult, but unnecessary). But we don't care what the actual number is; we just need to know how it compares to `N`. But we can see that the size of the span is at most `N` bits if the ratio of the last `1` to the last `0` (marker) is at most 2<sup>N</sup>.

So let's put all that together.

```
unsigned long fill_in_runs(unsigned long val, int N) {
  unsigned long k = val;
  while (k) {
    unsigned long last_zero = (k + 1) & ~k;
    k -= last_zero - 1;
    if (k) {
      unsigned long last_one = k & -k;
      if ((last_one >> N) <= last_zero) 
        val += last_one - last_zero;
      k += last_one - 1;
    } else if (last_zero > (1UL << (M - N - 1)))
      val -= last_zero;
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Lots of nice tricks, but this has a lot of branching and run time is O(M) rather than O(N).

Comment: I don't think `unsigned long last_one = k & -k;` works if `long` isn't bigger than `unsigned`.

Comment: @MarkB `unsigned long` and `long` are the same length, fwiw.

Comment: @R: fair point. I got it down to two compares per loop, but you're right about the number of loops (it's the number of 1's, but that's probably O(M)).

Answer (score 1):

I believe below code can do the needful for your requirement, how ever you can still optimize it, i leave it up to you...

```
#define BIT_GROUP   4

int main()
{
    uint32_t i, j, n;
    uint8_t bit_pos, zero_bit_pos, count;

    i = n = 0xaa05;

    printf("%x\n", i);

    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");

        n >>= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");

    n = i;
    bit_pos = count = 0;
    while(n)
    {
        if(!(n & 1))
        {
            if(count <= BIT_GROUP)
            {
                zero_bit_pos = bit_pos;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                zero_bit_pos = 0;
                count = 0;
                j = 0;
            }
            if(count <= BIT_GROUP)
            {
                j = ((1 << count) - 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            j <<= ((zero_bit_pos + 1) - count);
            i |= j;
            j = 0;
            zero_bit_pos = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
        bit_pos++;
        n >>= 1;
    }

    n = i;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");

        n >>= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%x\n", i);


    return 0;
}
```

hope it helps!!!!!!